# How to get all the error messages which are generated by isValid() chain?

Tags: validation, zend-framework, file-transfer

I check files with `Count` and `isImage` validators. I explicitly upload wrong number of files and wrong mime type files but it displays only one error message indicating that only one file is wrong. But I want to see all the files that are not valid. How to set this behavior?

Comment: can you please show us your code?

Comment: can you share your isValid code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [getMessages()](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/zf/Zend_Form.class.html#det_methods_getMessages) method of Zend_Form. It retrieves error messages from elements failing validations.